# Where to put events when using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, event-handling

Should I put all events in views code behind or there is a more proper way, like place commands in ViewModel?
For example, I want to open Tab on double click on the datagrid row, where should I handle this event?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No you should not put events in code behind. In  MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) design pattern, the view model is the component that is responsible for handling the application's presentation logic and state. This means that your view's code-behind file should contain no code to handle events that are raised from any user interface (UI) element.

for eg if you have button in your xaml

```xml
<Button Content="OK" Click="btn_Click"/>
```

```cs
protected void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   /* This is not MVVM! */
}
```

Instead you can use [WPF Command](http://www.wpftutorial.net/delegatecommand.html).All you have to do is bind to its Execute and CanExecute  delegates and invoke your command.

So your code will now be

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly DelegateCommand<string> _clickCommand;

    public ViewModel()
    {
         _clickCommand = new DelegateCommand(
        (s) => { /* perform some action */ }, //Execute
        null
    } //CanExecute );

    public DelegateCommand ButtonClickCommand
    {
       get { return _clickCommand; }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Button Content="COOL" Command="ButtonClickCommand"/>
```

Comment: I already know how to use command for button click events, but what about other events like row double click etc? They don't have command property.

Comment: you can also do this for other controls like for eg Datagrid has `SelectedCellsChanged` event which you can wire up to your viewmodel using `SelectedCellsChanged="{Binding YourCommand}" `

Comment: Looking for good MVVM solution myself, but just have to say that it's hard to justify "don't put things in the code behind" when there's not an out-of-the-box solution for the "right' way to do it.

Comment: `SelectedCellsChanged="{Binding YourCommand}"` gives you error "YourCommand is not a method."

Comment: Ok, but where are the `EventArgs`, how to use them?

Comment: is this still not supported out-of-the-box in .net and we have to write DelegateCommand class code in every project ourselves?

Answer (score 14):

Kyle is correct in that your handlers should appear in the view model. If a command property doesn't exist then you can use an interaction trigger instead:

```
<DataGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=OpenClientCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=searchResults, Path=SelectedItems}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    ... other stuff goes here ...

</DataGrid>
```

Or you can use MVVM Lite's EventToCommand, which also allows you to pass in the message parameters:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ClosingCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Which is used in in this case to cancel the window close event in response to the "Are you sure you want to quit?" dialog:

```cs
public ICommand ClosingCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<CancelEventArgs>(OnClosing); } }

private void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs args)
{
    if (UserCancelsClose())
        args.Cancel = true;
}
```

Relevant namespaces are as follows:

```xml
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:cmd ="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
```