# How to use events with MVVM in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

I am learning .NET MAUI, and the recommended architecture in [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Qga2pniN78&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oUBAdL2NwBpDs32zwGqb9DY&index=5) is MVVM. It uses attributes from the the MVVM toolkit (CommunityToolkit.MVVM) like [ObservableProperty]. I am needing to use this gesture recognizer in my XAML:

```
<Button.GestureRecognizers>
    <PointerGestureRecognizer PointerEntered="ButtonOnPointerEntered" PointerExited="ButtonOnPointerExit"/>
</Button.GestureRecognizers>
```

PointerEntered and PointerExited both need a method signature of `void MethodName(object sender, EventArgs e)`. In MVVM architecture (as I understand) you aren't supposed to have any code in the code-behind besides InitializeComponent() or any dependencies, but I haven't been able to find any way to format events for the ViewModel in the toolkit, and according to the answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669964/where-to-put-events-when-using-mvvm) (if I understand correctly), you aren't supposed to have events in MVVM. What is the correct way to go about this? Should I use MVVM at all?

Comment: if you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/pointer?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) you'll see that `PointerGestureRecognizer` has multiple commands available that can be used in the `ViewModel` instead of events

Comment: Aha. Thanks! Apologies for the oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a summary, I will post an answer.

I achieved this function on my side and tested it on windows.

1.create a view model `MyViewModel.cs`

```
public partial class MyViewModel:BindableObject
{
    public MyViewModel() {

    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void BtnOnPointerEntered() {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------> BtnOnPointerEntered");
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void BtnOnPointerMoved()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------> BtnOnPointerMoved");
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void BtnOnPointerExit()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------> BtnOnPointerExit");
    }
}
```

2.Usage example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiApp1225.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiApp1225.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MyViewModel></viewmodels:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Button Text="test">
              <Button.GestureRecognizers>
                <PointerGestureRecognizer PointerEnteredCommand="{Binding BtnOnPointerEnteredCommand}"
                                              PointerExitedCommand="{Binding BtnOnPointerExitCommand}"
                                              PointerMovedCommand="{Binding BtnOnPointerMovedCommand}"
                                             
                                              />
              </Button.GestureRecognizers>
            </Button>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Note:

For more information, please check document: [Recognize a pointer gesture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/pointer?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android).